# Animate a div onHover

Tags: css

I would like to rotate a div when the cursor is on the div like in [this video](https://youtu.be/ru6iSaSNvmI?t=325).

I would like to use keyframes because they are more customizable

```css
div.myElement {
    ...
    animation: mainMenu 2s infinite;
    animation-play-state: initial;
}

div.myElement:hover {
    animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes mainMenu {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
}
```

It doesn't work but i don't know what I need to put in my div.myElement and div.myElement:hover. In div.Element, it is 0% to 100% and 100% to 0% for div.Element:hover.

Comment: `paused` not `initial`

Comment: you have to use  animation-play-state: paused; on your div.myElement

Comment: Look the video before, i don't want to pause my animation when it's not hover, i just want to go to 0% to 100% of my keyframes and when it's hover 100% to 0%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an animation of a box, like you code sample 
https://jsfiddle.net/gnox69pv/5/

**HTML**

```
<div class="myElement"></div>
<div class="myElement"></div>
<div class="myElement"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
    div.myElement {

    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin:10px;
    animation: change_width_back 0.7s forwards;
}
div.myElement:hover {
    animation: change_width 0.7s forwards;
}
@keyframes change_width {
     0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
}
@keyframes change_width_back {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice !! But, you cannot compact and create only one keyframe sequence ?

Comment: You have created 2 keyframes 'change_width' and 'change_width_back'

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div.myElement {
    width : 100px;
    height : 100px;
    background-color : red;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    animation-play-state: initial;
}

div.myElement:hover {
 animation: mainMenu 2s infinite;
    animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes mainMenu {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="myElement"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and if you want the box will stay in the same stage use this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div.myElement {
    width : 100px;
    height : 100px;
    background-color : red;
    animation: mainMenu 2s infinite;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

div.myElement:hover {
    animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes mainMenu {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="myElement"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't work Tomer Raitz
```css
animation-play-state: paused;
animation-play-state: running;
```
This repeat the animation when you are hover, look that Ahmet does (and that is the good one) : https://jsfiddle.net/prbLhxud/

Comment: It works fine if you will look again on my answer you will see there are two answers. one is the animation get back to the '0deg'. and the other the animation "is stuck" on the deg of the hover timing. @Singularity I didn't know what is your need so I posted the two answers.